# HTML <range> initial value is jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the  element as a video seek bar, and am using the below jQuery to update the position of the 'thumb' during playback. However, this code is causing the element to ignore it's initial set value of "0", and instead positions the thumb in the center of the 'track'.

Can I update this code to ensure the initial value is respected?

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<input type="range" id="seek-bar" value="0" step="0.05">
```

**jQuery**

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  // Calculate the slider value
  var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;

  // Update the slider value
  seekBar.value = value;
});
```

Comment: pls give us a snippet; what does "video" refer to?

Comment: Sorry, code updated!

Comment: I need a snippet my friend; ur code is stil not complete.. i cant help u if u wont let me.

Comment: I would start by setting the min="0" and max="100" attributes on the range input, then I'd only change the value if the video is playing: `if(!video.paused) {/* calculate and set the seekvar value}; */

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram what do you mean? The entire code snippit is above.

Comment: @JonasGiuro - Thanks! Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. The min/max has no effect, as when I disable the above jquery the thumb position returns to 0 as expected. However, the if(!video.paused) function doesn't work either, it just breaks the code so the value doesn't update during playback?

Comment: It does work, I added an answer with a working example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an `oncanplay` listener to the video, and additionally only update the range input if the video is not paused. Also, I'd add the min and max attributes to the range input to make sure it goes from 0 to 100.

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var seekBar = document.getElementById("seekBar");

video.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {

    if (!video.paused) {
      // Calculate the slider value
      var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;

      // Update the slider value
      seekBar.value = value;
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<video id="video" style="width:600px;max-width:100%;" controls="">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
  
<input id="seekBar" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I think the added event listener of "canplay" makes all the difference here, tested and working :)